# Can box-shadow CSS property have padding?

Tags: css, reactjs

Is it possible to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSa2e.png) red countour at a distance from the shape using box-shadow property?

Comment: What is the shape? Is it an image? A collection of divs? An SVG?

Comment: @bowlowl it is a matrix which uses instances of  a react component that is mostly a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add two shadows, and make the inner one have the same color as the background. I don't like this approach though and would rather use `border` and `outline` for that.

```css
div {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 8px #FFFFFF, 0px 0px 0px 17px #CCC7CA;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Without `box-shadow`:

```css
#background {
  background-color: darkblue;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 50px;
}

#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: aquamarine padding-box;
  border: 8px transparent solid;
  outline: 9px #CCC7CA solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this looks fine. Eventually i would use a mathgrid component  to be the background as seen in the picture.wouldn't this come with some sort of visual conflicts?

Comment: You wouldn't have a transparent background, I'll update my answer to for an option to do that without `box-shadow`

Comment: the reason i've chosen `box-shadow` for this is that i will need to use a `@keyframe` to make it blink.

Comment: Since `box-shadow` essentially is just a blurrable box beneath the element I'm not sure if it's possible to have the gap to be transparent.